# Trying to hyperlink gridview item in its column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, ado.net

I have one form where data added dynamically in gridview I want to make one of the field item hyperlinked and redirect to next page .but not getting hyperlink. Any idea would be appreciated for making it hyperlink.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial" style="display: none"
    Font-Size="10pt" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor = "White">
                <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "TDC_NO" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("TDC_NO", "~/Uncoated_Wire.aspx?Id={0}") %>'
                    Text='<%# Eval("TDC_NO") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
                 <%--   <asp:HyperLinkField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataTextField="TDC_NO" DataNavigateUrlFields="TDC_NO" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Uncoated_Wire.aspx?TDC_NO={0}"
            HeaderText="TDC_NO"/>--%>                 
                    <%--<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="TDC_NO" HeaderText="TDC_NO" />--%>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="REVISION" HeaderText="REVISION" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="REVISION_DATE" HeaderText="REVISION_DATE" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="P_GROUP" HeaderText="P_GROUP" />                       
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

I tried in both ways using ItemTemplateField and  using HuperlinkField as above but items bind in gridview is not hyperlinked.
Gridview populate code  in aspx

```
<%--GridView Populate--%> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#THistory").click(function (event) {               
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#pdfFormInsideL1").hide();
                document.getElementById('<%=gvCustomers.ClientID%>').style.display = 'block';
                //$("#gvCustomers").show();
                $("#gvCustomers").attr("visibility", "visible");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TDC.aspx/GetCustomers",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            });
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var customers = xml.find("Table");
                var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
                $.each(customers, function () {
                    var customer = $(this);
                    $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("TDC_NO").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("REVISION").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("REVISION_DATE").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("P_GROUP").text());
                    $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
                    row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
     <%--GridView Populate--%>
```

C# code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetCustomers()
    {
        string query = "SELECT TDC_NO,REVISION,REVISION_DATE, P_GROUP from tdc_product1 ";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query);
        return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
    }
    private static DataSet GetData(OracleCommand cmd)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are filling a GridView with jQuery and Ajax and are wondering why aspnet Controls within the GridView are not working? Maybe you should rethink what you are doing and learn the difference between client and server side.

Comment: _"Trying to heperlink gridview item in its column"_  <-- needs review

Comment: @VDWWD yes i am filling a GridView with jQuery and Ajax . and as per my findings i found the way which i mentioned but how to do exactly any idea.

Comment: Just create a html link and put it in the GridView.

Comment: @VDWWD how can u show some example.